# mypy `type(x) is y` does not narrow values

Tags: python, mypy

I have this code

```
class Base:
    pass


class Foo(Base):
    foo: str


def bar(x: Base):
    if type(x) is Foo:
        return x.foo
    return ""
```

*mypy* gives me this error

```
$ mypy cast.py
cast.py:11: error: "Base" has no attribute "foo"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

On documentation it seems that mypy supports `type(x) is y` for narrowing types, documentation at https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html#type-narrowing-expressions

Still I have this error. I can use `isinstance(x, y)` but `isinstance` is less efficient than `type(x) is y` on worst case (which I have a lot on the code). I can also fix it with a cast, which is undesirable noise to me :

```
def bar(x: Base):
    if type(x) is Foo:
        return cast(Foo, x).foo
```

so today I'm ignoring this errors with `# type: ignore`, which is far from ideal too

Comment: What version of `mypy` are you using? I don't get that error with version 0.930.

Comment: I can successfully reproduce this error in mypy 0.800. Possibly a bug that was fixed in a newer one?

Comment: What looks like the [relevant pull request](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/10284) (April 2021) was merged sometime between 0.812 (February 2021) and 0.900 (June 2021).

Comment: you're right, was the version, I was on 08xx now 0941, no more errors, THANKS!

Comment: @chepner post as an answer and I accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using an older version of `mypy`; what [appears to be](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/10284) the pull request that added type-narrowing with the use of `type` was added in April 2021, between the 0.812 and 0.900 releases. Newer versions of `mypy`, at least, work as documented.

```
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.930

$ mypy tmp.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```